# Eclipse feature: independent panel/areas resize. Where should I ask this question?

Tags: support, questions, scope

I just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909500/eclipse-feature-switch-independent-panel-areas-resize) on SO.

Actually I figured out there is other questions about [eclipse features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793570/changing-the-case-of-a-string-in-eclipse) or [configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640884/how-can-i-show-line-numbers-in-eclipse), but there are not exactly programmatic question but includes an IDE...

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**.

Is a valid SO question? Or there is a better forum for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first set of bullet in [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) specifies which topics should be covered by StackOverflow. The third bullet there states:

> software tools commonly used by programmers

Eclipse definitely falls under that category.

TL;DR - StackOverflow is the right place for this question.

Comment: thanks @M just wanted to confirm... We, the SO users, are so rude sometimes... XD